# Can't create one to many relationship on same model

Tags: laravel

I want to create `sponsors` users on my website. I use the same model as relationship.

User.php (model):

```
public function sponsor(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'sponsored_id', 'sponsor_id');
}

public function sponsored(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->BelongsTo(self::class, 'sponsor_id', 'sponsored_id');
}
```

Sponsor rows :

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreignId('sponsor_id')->nullable();
    $table->foreignId('sponsored_id')->nullable();
});
```

My UserSeeder:

```
$sponsor = User::factory()->create(['name' => 'sponsor']);

$sponsor->sponsor()->save(
    User::factory()->make()
);
```

Comment: what is not working? what's the issue?

Comment: null returned when i write $sponsor->sponsor->first()

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment you are trying to retrieve one record from sponser so it should be

```
$sponsor->sponsor()->first()
```

Comment: i thought too, but null returned :'(

Comment: @ValentinLeguy.is there data relating to that relationship.is it possible to show table structure and some data